# answerInlineQuery was successfully sended but no result actually

Tags: telegram-bot

I have code for cover inlineQuery:

- inline mode was turned on in BotFather
- webhooks with InlineQuery correctly recived
- result for answerInlineQuery is: `{ "ok": true, "result": true }`

Bot JavaScript code (BJS) written on Bots.Business:

```
results = [];
item = {
  type: "article",
  id: "13",
  title: "Test item",
  input_message_content: { "message_text": "this is text" }
}
results.push(item);

Api.answerInlineQuery({
  inline_query_id: request.id,
  results: results,
  cache_time: 0,
  on_result: "/trackResult"
})
```

/trackResult command (it handle after answerInlineQuery method):

```
throw inspect(options)
```

In error log (I just track successfull notice as error):

[image: correct response from Telegram Api]

So: answerInlineQuery was sended but actually **no any inline results** for user in the Telegram chat.

Answer (score 0):

```
results = [];
item = {
  type: "article",
  id: "13",
  title: "Test item",
  input_message_content: '{ "message_text": "this is text" }'
}
results.push(item);

Api.answerInlineQuery({
  inline_query_id: request.id,
  results: results,
  cache_time: 0,
  on_result: "/trackResult"
})
```

Need pass input_message_content as string